# Make two apps communicate when one isn't written as a native app

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got an interesting situation here that I'm looking for some ideas for...

I'm working on writing a custom launcher and I want to do it with the Corona SDK.  For those that aren't familiar with Corona, it's a Lua-based platform that, at the end of the day (and what matters most for this discussion) spits out a signed APK to install.  For the time being, I just threw together a very simple app that shows some icons for apps I know are present (calendar, clock, etc).

Now, what I've done is I've written a native Android launcher app that, in onCreate(), does a package-based launch of the Corona app.  In other words, my native app is nothing but a simple stub to launch the real launcher.  Since there's no way (without hacking the APK anyway) to manipulate what Corona generates, this seemed like a reasonably clever approach that seems to work.

Now, here's the problem: there's no way I can see in Corona to (a) get a list of installed apps and (b) launch apps.  Obviously, those are problems :)

So, the question I have for you all is what clever ways can you think of to allow these two apps to communicate?  Because, I know how to get the list of installed apps in native Android code, and I know how to launch them... so, I'm thinking, if there's a way I can pass the list to the Corona app, and then have the Corona app ask the native stub app to launch apps on it's behalf, I'd actually have a launcher.

I was thinking one "easy" answer would be to have the stub app respond to HTTP requests, since Corona does provide the equivalent of AJAX functionality.  So, I could do a simple REST interface between them in theory... problem is, I'm not aware of how you'd make a native app essentially function as a mini web server.  I did some looking around but couldn't find an answer.  Obviously, things like Jetty exist, so there must be a way, but I don't know if they are written with the NDK, which I DON'T want to get into for this.

So, any ideas on coding a web server with plain old Java code on Android?  Or, failing that, any other clever ideas to allow the two apps to communicate?  Or, of course, is there another alternative I'm not even thinking of?

Thanks!

EDIT: After further research, Corona does support things like working with intents... in fact, it supports calling native code, so in theory I could do it all from the Corona side... problem is, you need to be subscribed to their Enterprise level, and I'm only at Pro and very much doubt I could afford an Enterprise subscription even if I wanted to... so, I'm not feeling confident about being able to do this.  Also, to answer the questions about why not just do a native app, it's simply because Corona is fantastic for what it does, and writing a launcher with it would be a piece of cake (these issues aside of course) and you could do some fantastic things that way.  Part of it certainly just the "can I do it?" factor, but part of it is because I frankly like working with Corona as opposed to native Android code and would prefer to do so if I can... it's not looking good though :(

Comment: This sounds a lot more complicated than if you had just built it using the native tools.

Comment: Can you do broadcast receipt and sending via the corona app?  If so just have it send "broadcasts" to your launcher app, which upon receipt does the nescesary work (I.E. looks up avail apps, returns these to your corona app, launches other apps etc..).  It's basically what you're doing to launch the Corona app, but in reverse.

Comment: While their documentation looks poor, it's pretty hard to imagine that they would not provide a way for you to work with Intents.  Also, to some extent, you can send an Intent by opening a URL.

Comment: If, for some insane reason they won't let you use intents (...why are you even using this then?) you could also implement this via shared preferences, or a file write/read mechanism, but that would be horrendous and a huge waste of time imo.  Better off just writing it natively as the first comenter suggests.